# ps2pdf is not working anymore - Macport upgrade on MacOS High Sierra 10.13.5

Tags: pdftex, dvips, ghostscript, ps2pdf, macos

After an upgrading following a break dependency on my MacOS High Sierra 10.13.5, the command "`ps2pdf`" doesn't work anymore.

I use it with latex to convert a ghostscript file `.ps`, generated from `latex` compiler and `dvips` command.

Here is below the error I get with `ps2pdf` : `$ ps2pdf file.ps`

```
While reading gs_ll3.ps:
Error: /undefinedresource in findresource
Operand stack:
   (gs_icc.ps\000gs_mex_e.ps\000gs_mro_e.ps\000gs_pdf_e.ps\000gs_wan_e.ps\000pdf_ops.ps\000gs_l2img.ps\000pdf_rbld.ps\000pdf_base.ps\000pdf_draw.ps\000pdf_font.ps\000pdf_main.ps\000pdf_sec.ps\000gs_cff.ps\000gs_mgl_e.ps\000gs_ttf.ps\000gs_dps.ps\000gs_dpn...)   (gs_ll3.ps)   1   Pscript5Idiom.mp_1554149595   IdiomSet   6   Pscript5Idiom.mp_1554149595
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   --nostringval--   findresource   %loop_continue   findresource   findresource   findresource   false   1   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   1969   7   5   %oparray_pop   findresource   findresource   --dict:16/18(ro)(G)--   --dict:2/2(G)--   findresource   2   %dict_continue   findresource   findresource   1967   5   5   %oparray_pop   findresource   %errorexec_pop   findresource   findresource   findresource   findresource
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:1050/1123(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:72/200(L)--   --dict:1050/1123(G)--   --dict:40/43(G)--   --dict:16/18(ro)(G)--
Current allocation mode is global
Current file position is 18894
```

A solution is to use instead `pstopdf` but this binary doesn't produce `href URL link` on pdf generated output file : that's why I would like to make work the classical binary `ps2pdf`.

I tried to uninstall ghostscript macport and reinstall it but this doesn't change anything.

I have also tried with `pdflatex` but there are some errors too :

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 45--46

! Undefined control sequence.
\c@lor@to@ps ->\PSTricks 
                         _Not_Configured_For_This_Format
l.54 \sepline

? 
! Undefined control sequence.
\XC@usec@lor ...string \color@ #1#2\endcsname \@@ 
                                                  \fi \space 
l.54 \sepline

? 
! Undefined control sequence.
\c@lor@to@ps ->\PSTricks 
                         _Not_Configured_For_This_Format
l.54 \sepline

? 
...
```

Any suggestion or help is welcome, regards.

Comment: After a reinstall some dependencies may have changed so likely candidates are different behaviours or missing components or worse duplicate versions of dvips tools such as auto-pst-pdf needing a perl script to run pdfcrop so worth checking locations and numbers of each package/component and their status for running as a resource (folder rights path alias etc.)

Comment: You could try `xelatex`, which internally converts dvi to pdf (properly processing PSTricks code) without needing `ps2pdf` or `pstopdf`. This also preserves hyperlinks.

Comment: Finally, I recompiled ghoscript from Linux sources and replaced the binary. Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ps2pdf is included in the Ghostscript package. Thus first, verify that you already have installed. In the terminal window try with:

```
find /usr/local/ -name ps2pdf
```

Then, you will receive the new location of the 'ps2pdf' file. In my case it was '/usr/local//Cellar/ghostscript/9.50/bin/ps2pdf'. If you don't have installed the Ghostscript package, try to install it by using brew package manager:

```
brew install ghostscript
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, make sure the command "brew" works. If not, please try to install" homebrew" via typing the following code in the Terminal

```
ruby -e"$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Then, install ghostscript

```
brew install ghostscript
```